# Autentificar usuario y que identifique su rol o grupo al que pertenece Django

Tags: python, django, autenticación

Como creo una autentificar un usuario con email y contraseña, y después al logueo le muestre un menú según el rol o al grupo al que pertenezca.

**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from Apps.persona.models import Person
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    Group,
    )


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Usuuario tiene email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("usuario debe tener contraseña")
        user_obj = self.model(
            email =self.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff  = is_staff
        user_obj.admin  = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
                email,
                password=password,
                is_staff=True,
                is_admin=True
        )
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email  = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    REQUIRED_FILES = ['person']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('user')
        verbose_name_plural = ('users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email


    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

En usuario estoy usando AbstracBaseUser y que contiene un BaseUserManager